# How to ensure a block of code is executed by only one thread in parallel processing in java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a test class that is run using maven command line that looks like this:

```
public class TestRunner {

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testParallel() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {


         //Takes 5 mins. Has 20 different tests with the tag @e2eDTC
         Results DTC = Runner.path("classpath:").tags("@e2eDTC").reportDir("target/cucumber-html- 
         reports").parallel(1);
         assertTrue(DTC.getErrorMessages(), DTC.getFailCount() == 0); 
         generateReport(DTC.getReportDir());

        // Takes 4 min. Has 25 different tests the tag @e2eWNG
         Results WNG = Runner.path("classpath:").tags("@e2eWNG").reportDir("target/cucumber-html- 
         reports").parallel(1);
         assertTrue(WNG.getErrorMessages(), WNG.getFailCount() == 0); 
         generateReport(WNG.getReportDir());

         // Takes 3 min. Has 18 different tests with the tag @e2eFFD
         Results FFD = Runner.path("classpath:").tags("@e2eFFD").reportDir("target/cucumber-html- 
         reports").parallel(1);
         assertTrue(FFD.getErrorMessages(), FFD.getFailCount() == 0); 
         generateReport(FFD.getReportDir());

        }
}
```

The above code is clearly sequential and takes a little over 12 mins. . I wish to introduce parallelism such that each block of code(with a particular tag) with the 3 lines of Results object, assertion and generation or report is run in parallel by a single thread each. So the overall processing time would be theoritically a little over 5 mins. Meaning the block with DTC runs on a thread, block of WNG runs on different thread and block of FFD runs on seperate thread. Within each block only one thread is fine.

I tried to use Executor Service and here is the code

```
public class TestRunner {

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testParallel() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
         ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

        Set<Callable<String>> callables = new HashSet<Callable<String>>();

        callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() throws Exception {
                Results DTC = Runner.path("classpath:").tags("@e2eDTC").reportDir("target/cucumber-html-reports").parallel(1);
                assertTrue(DTC.getErrorMessages(), DTC.getFailCount() == 0); 
                generateReport(DTC.getReportDir());
                return "DTC Success";
            }
        });
        callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() throws Exception {
                Results WNG = Runner.path("classpath:").tags("@e2eWarnings").reportDir("target/cucumber-html-reports").parallel(1);
                assertTrue(WNG.getErrorMessages(), WNG.getFailCount() == 0); 
                generateReport(WNG.getReportDir());
                return "WNG Success";
            }
        });
        callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() throws Exception {
                Results FFD = Runner.path("classpath:").tags("@e2eFFD").reportDir("target/cucumber-html-reports").parallel(1);
                assertTrue(FFD.getErrorMessages(), FFD.getFailCount() == 0); 
                generateReport(FFD.getReportDir());
                return "FFD Success";
            }
        });
        List<Future<String>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(callables);

        for(Future<String> future : futures){
            System.out.println("future.get = " + future.get());
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
}
```

However this  gives us 3 threads and it randomly assigns the threads to the multiple tests within each block and causes errors.

Changing

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
```

to

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
```

makes it a sequential program once again.
I want it such that thread 1 is assigned to the tag @e2eDTC and run the tests with that tag only and in the same way thread 2 to @e2eWNG and thread 3 to @e2eFFD. Is it possible to have such a setup? I am not a java developer and hence seek some advice on how to acheive this. There is no main() method too here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HashSet is not thread safe. You can create a synchronizedSet with

```
  Set<Callable<String>> callables = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Callable<String>>());
```

Or you can use ArrayList

```
 List<Callable<String>> tasksList = new ArrayList<Callable<String>>();
```

I do not think executor pool service you would need because you will have no control because threads are assigned by OS. You could use the below code

```
    public class ThreadTest {

    @org.junit.Test
public void testFunc() {
    ThreadTest test = new ThreadTest();

    Thread a = new Thread(test.new DTC());
    Thread b = new Thread(test.new WNG());
    Thread c = new Thread(test.new FFD());

    a.start();
    b.start();
    c.start();
}


class DTC implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Your logic
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("DTC Success " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
     }
    }

    class WNG implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
             // Your logic
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("WNG Success "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
     }
    }

    class FFD implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
         // Your logic
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("FFD Success "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
     }
    }

     }
```

Comment: Your solution was quite useful and performs very well. however I do get some random failures at times. Is this expected?@Pakira

Comment: thank you very much for this. This looks very cleaner and really like your solution. The issue I am facing is that it has  the main method to invoke it. Since I am using a maven test command to run this file, including main method gives me the following error ```Tests in error:
  initializationError(eCare.ThreadTest): Method main() should not be static
  initializationError(eCare.ThreadTest): Method main should have no parameters``` If I renamed the main to another method name like ```public void testParallel() throws InterruptedException{``` it does not execute the tests at all.

Comment: Looks like a trival issue somewhere that I may be missing now @Pakira

Comment: Thanks @Pakira. It doesn't look like its overriding and executing the run() method. I put prints for debugging, but it doesnt seem to be enter the run() method execution at all. Any ideas? I am looking for more information as well.

Comment: changed start() to run() and seems to be working. Have some issues but it seems to be working for me. Read that for various reasons start() doesnt work but run() does. Will dig deeper and leave my findings here. Thanks for all your help @Pakira